# Grid Method Multiplication

Tags: math-mode, diagrams, mathematics

I am trying to write a document on some elementary algebra but I'm quite new to LaTeX. I'm currently using overleaf and would like to draw a box method multiplication. I could add them in as images but I may edit them so want to make them in latex. Below is an example of what I would like to produce.

[image]

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: This is not super hard to draw using tikz.

Comment: See the box as a set of lines (to draw with TikZ). Then, you can create "nodes" at, e. g. (0, 1) with label "-3".

Comment: @daleif I'm unfamiliar with TikZ, could you provide a template please? Do I need to add an extra package or is it part of TeX?

Comment: You need the `tikz` package. There are many examples online, see for instance https://texample.net/tikz/examples/

Comment: @daleif Thanks, I'll take a look. A quick search shows no examples of box multiplication. - I'm currently looking after a 3 week old baby whilst trying to work on this project if you can offer any more hand holding, I'd appreciate it. If not, I'll try my best to put it all together :)